# Columns in SQLPlus report display longer than database column size

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a number of sql reports that used to work fine. Recently however they have started to be outputted with the column widths being longer than they should. According to Oracle's documentation if a column in an sql report has no explicit "`COLUMN`" definition at the start of the report, eg '`column example_col heading "Eg col" format A50`', it should display with a width that is the same as the column's definition in the database table, ie if the column is defined as `varchar2(10)` it should display with a width of 10 characters.

Previously this was fine however recently some of these columns have started being displayed with a larger width which is causing the lines of the report to extend past the linesize onto a second line thus making the report less readable.

I just wanted to see if anybody may have come across this behaviour before and might know what could be the cause? Below are before and after pictures of one of the reports so you can see the problem.

[report before problems started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twnnP.jpg)

[report after problems started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3w6zC.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure that the column widths haven't changed? In sqlplus, try the describe command on the table: `desc mytable`

Comment: I thought of this also but it looks like the definition of the tables hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem is in setting the NLS_LANG environment variable to AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8. This causes column widths to be extended when output in SQLPlus. The solution was to change this environment variable to AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1.

The details from the relevant Oracle Metalink are as follows:

> Symptoms
> Running the same statement in different SQL*Plus sessions
> results in different length off the output.
>
> Session 1:
>
> SQL> select sysdate, sysdate from dual;
> SYSDATE         SYSDATE
>
> ---
>
> 30-OCT-08       30-OCT-08
>
> Session 2:
>
> SQL> select sysdate, sysdate from dual;
> SYSDATE   SYSDATE
>
> ---
>
> 30-OCT-08 30-OCT-08
>
> Cause
> The NLS_LANG character set determines how the output will be presented.
>
> When using multibyte character sets column widths will be larger.
> Solution Set character set for NLS_LANG to get wanted output. If you
> need "long" output, use UTF8 as character set. Make sure the client OS
> can handle the character set chosen.

Answer (score 0):

`COLUMN` it is, from my point of view.

- looks like *report before problems started* used column formatting so that output looks nice
- looks like *report after problems started* doesn't use column formatting any more

The question is: what changed between "before" and "after"? A few possibilities:

- `COLUMN` formatting lines were removed
- `CLEAR COLUMNS` was used, so all column settings were lost
- check

  - `.SQL` files you use to create reports
  - `login.sql`
  - `glogin.sql`